# Wordoress How to Capture get variable in url during login

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating an application where I have to save some get variable during login in  WordPress, I have tried to use the `wp_login` hook with no success, I have also used `wp_authenticate` to capture the get variable among other methods with no success.

To make it more clear this is how I'm sending my get variable

`https://localhost:8080/wp-login.php?wper=some_value` or `https://localhost:8080/sign-in/?wper=some_value`

Now what I need is to save get variable `$_GET['wper']` in the database upon login, or rather upon clicking the login button.

please note my website uses two logins form, one is a custom login form from a plugin and the other one is the native wordpress login which is wp_login.php

the following is my code and my trial

```
function your_function( $username, $password ) {
    if( is_email( $username ) ){
        $user = get_user_by( 'email', $username ); 
    } else {
        $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
    }
    if( !$user ){
    } else {
        update_user_meta( $user->ID, '_wper_data', $_GET['wper'], '' );
    }
}
add_action('wp_authenticate', 'your_function', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $_GET is not getting passed with the form or via URL.

So one method would be to add it to the form submission.

```
add_action('wp_authenticate', 'your_function', 10, 1);
function your_function( $username ) {

    if( is_email( $username ) ){
        $user = get_user_by( 'email', $username );
    } else {
        $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
    }
    if( $user && isset( $_POST['_wper_data'] ) ){
        update_user_meta( $user->ID, '_wper_data', $_POST['_wper_data'], '' );
    }
}

add_action( 'login_form', 'custom_hidden_login_field', 10, 0 );
function custom_hidden_login_field() { ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="_wper_data" value="<?php echo $_GET['wper']; ?>" />
    <?php
}
```